# Write bzip2 version information to file

Tags: shell, unix, io-redirection, bzip2

I'm trying to write the result of:

```
bzip2 --version
```

to a file.  However, nothing seems to be able to "see" the version info that's printed onto the screen.  For example:

```
bzip2 --version > test.txt
```

creates an empty file and

```
bzip2 --version | grep Version
```

prints the entire paragraph of text, whereas

```
gcc --version | grep gcc
```

prints only the line with "gcc" on it.

What is bzip2's --version flag doing differently, and how do I capture it's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `bzip --version` is written to stderr, not stdout, so it has to be redirected with `2>` instead of a plain old `>`:

```
mureinik@computer ~ $ bzip2 --version 2> test.txt
```